# Print Euro symbol € using python module by converting the unicode character u'\u20ac'

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to print the currency symbol using python. I am able to print some currency symbols by normalizing the unicode character.Because in python 2.7, in the character map, I can see mappings only for some unicode characters and not for EURO symbol that is '\u20ac'.

To print EURO symbol, do we need to include the unicode characters the character map python file?

OR is there any other way which we can use to print the EURO symbol?

I use the below code and I am getting below error.

Output:

Yen

¥

Euro

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\new-test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print list1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import unicodedata

list  = ['Yen','\u00a5','Euro',u'\u20ac']

for character in list:    
        list1 = (unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", character)).strip()
        print list1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows command prompt is configured to use code page 437 (`cp437`) and the Euro symbol is not defined in that encoding.  You can change the code page to 1252 which supports the character:

```
C:\>py -2
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\u20ac'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> ^Z


C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>py -2
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\u20ac'
€
```

A better alternative is to switch to Python 3.6 or later, which uses Windows Unicode APIs to write directly to the console, bypassing encoding issues:

```
C:\>py -3
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u20ac')
€
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am able to print if I modify the code page as I need to use python 2.7

Comment: @mvsz If the answer was useful, consider upvoting. You can also accept one answer as the best for your question.

Comment: I tried earlier but it restricted me doing that. Now I am able to do that. Done.

Comment: Can I do chcp inside python code also to automate the steps?

Comment: @mvsz Easier to switch to python 3, but you can automate it. Post another question.

Comment: Is there any other way to normalize the unicode characters instead of code page change or switching to python 3? Because, there may have some issue if any other symbols are not there in activated codepage. If yes, I will post another question for that.

Comment: @mvsz Most code page generally only supports 256 Unicode code points, except for specialized ones like Japanese or Chinese.  Python 3.6+ supports any Unicode code point the terminal can display, but still requires font support.  Python 2 support is being dropped in 2020.  Switch if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unichr() function

```
print unichr(8364)
```